# Using MySQL LIMIT on query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, limit

I'm doing the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.ID, wp_terms.name, wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON ( wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id ) 
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

This returns 50 results as expected : But dependant on the number of 'terms' per 'post', this would mean an indeterminate number of 'posts'.

How can I limit it so that I get 25 unique wp_posts

```
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
```

But return as many rows as I need with regards to joined wp_terms... ?

Thanks!

Comment: does `unique/distinct` work in `select statement`?

Answer (score 0):

If due to LEFT joins, there may be more than one entry for a given ID, I would pre-query from your posts, the most recent 25 IDs that qualify as your left-joins are optional and you are always getting the ID.  Limit this to 25.  Now, when applying the ORDER BY to the JustLast25.ID, will put as many sequentially assigned entries along with it.  So, your 25 IDs could generate 200 entries, but for each ID, they will be assigned a sequence of 1, 2, 3, etc...

After that is all wrapped-up, in order to get your 50 record limit, but ensuring you have all 25 of your IDs, you need to re-query from that, but change the order to the sequence FIRST, then the ID so you get the 1st entry for every possible, then 2nd for every possible, then 3rd, etc... Some may have no entries, but a minimum, they will be included in the list once.  For those that have more than one, their additional records will appear after the first run

```
select
      PreQualify.*
   from
      ( SELECT 
              JustLast25.post_date, 
              JustLast25.post_content, 
              JustLast25.post_title, 
              JustLast25.ID, 
              wp_terms.name, 
              wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy,
              @lastSeq := if( @lastID = JustLast25.id, @lastSeq +1, 1 ) as SeqPerID,
              @lastID := JustLast25.ID
           FROM 
              ( select @lastID := 0, @lastSeq := 0 ) sqlvars,
              ( select wp_posts.*
                   from wp_posts
                   where wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
                      AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                   ORDER BY 
                      wp_posts.ID DESC
                   LIMIT 25 ) JustLast25

                 LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
                    ON JustLast25.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
                    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
                       ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
                       LEFT JOIN wp_terms 
                          ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
           order by
              JustLast25.ID DESC ) PreQualify
   order by
      PreQualify.SeqPerID,
      PreQualify.ID DESC
   LIMIT 50
```

Now, if you want them all to be grouped with all the records next to their sequentially qualified postings, you'll have to wrap that up one more level into

```
select
      FinalSet.*
   from
      ( full query from above ) FinalSet
   order by
      FinalSet.ID DESC,
      FinalSet.SeqPerID
```